# Fit column size html

Tags: html, html-table

I've been looking around but there's too much information about tables that's why I cannot find my answer.

I need 2 menus but with same top align. If I put different content on each columns each column has different height. I tried to set height inside td tags, table tags, modify padding and margin styles everywhere, but no way.

I need to do more than 50 menus, so I hope you can tell me a solution that's not `<td height="150px">` or something like that, I need a solution through margin. Something close to a template.

Code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3zqLT/1/

```
<table border="1"><tr><td>

<table><tr><td>
    Menu 1
<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ul>

</td></tr></table>

</td><td>

<table height="100%"><tr><td>
Menu 2
<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ul>

</td></tr></table>

</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

Hope you  can help me out.

Edit: The reason why I'm using tables is because I need some menus in the same height, from left to right, not from up to down.

Edit: I found a solution with divs and no table. But I'd like to know how to fix this with tables.

Comment: Don't use tables for markup unless you're showing data. Are you?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve? Also a example of code on http://jsfiddle.net helps you to clearify you question and helps users to give the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following CSS code seems to help.

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

If for any chance your new to CSS, [here](http://w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)'s some reading on how to implement CSS.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Appreciated mate.